# Exploiting preg_replace /e modifier in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently tinkering with a hacking challenge where the goal is to output `phpinfo()` on the page. After some poking around I've found that the injection point is the search page as it runs preg_replace with the 'e' modifier on the search query. I've been able to trigger errors with inputs such as "`) blah`" and "`b|exit(phpinfo());`" but unfortunately I'm not sure how to phrase my injection so that preg_replace actually runs it.

The confusing part I haven't wrapped my head entirely around is that the regular expression seems to be matching names that correspond to those listed on the page, but only if said input is 3 characters or greater in length. I deduced that I would have to find a way to both match the regular expression and then append some code to the end so it evaluates `phpinfo()` as a command instead of a string.

Does anyone have some more insight to what is going on, and how to crack this?

Answer (score 3):

The `/e` modifier allows a second argument to be evaluated as a PHP expression.

So if you were to do something like:

```
$string = "phpinfo()";
print preg_replace('/^(.*)/e', 'strtoupper(\\1)', $string);
```

This would fire the function and print the PHP info. Depending on how the search is set up, you can modify to print properly. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm unable to see the page you referenced above since I don't have an account so I'm a bit limited there. But you saying the search function on the page is to search for names on the page, is that the case?

Comment: If the 2nd argument is coming as plain text, perhaps it means the 2nd argument isn't being evaluated as a PHP expression. This could be multiple things though, so I don't have any exact info on the matter. Perhaps try escaping the query so your call to print the `phpinfo()` is executed.